# c++ dynamic library linking in MacOsX

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

**If you want to watch source codes, download them here goo.gl/pGJwn1.**

When i've written my program all files were in a unique directory and the compiling was ok.
Now i want to create a dynamic library for each package and link them. 
I'm using a MacOsX.
When I compile the "AnalysisFramework" package i use this command
`c++-4.8 -std=c++0x -fPIC -shared -o libAnalysisFramework.so *.cc  -I../ -I. -Wall` and all it's ok.

The problems occurs when i try to compile the "AnalysisObjects" package. In fact, using the same command the compiler returns these errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Event::minSize()", referenced from:
      BraggStatistic::BraggStatistic(int, int) in ccWYudnZ.o
      BraggStatistic::BraggStatistic(int, int) in ccWYudnZ.o
      BraggStatistic::add(Event const&) in ccWYudnZ.o
      BraggStatistic::compute()      in ccWYudnZ.o
      TotalEnergy::update(Event const&) in ccoA1A2B.o
  "Constants::bgMean", referenced from:
      BraggStatistic::compute()      in ccWYudnZ.o
      TotalEnergy::energy()      in ccoA1A2B.o
  "Event::energy(unsigned int) const", referenced from:
      BraggStatistic::add(Event const&) in ccWYudnZ.o
      TotalEnergy::update(Event const&) in ccoA1A2B.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It doesn't find the functions definitions that are in the other directory. Is it normal? How fix?

I've these directory with source codes.

```
|____AnalysisFramework
| |____AnalysisFactory.cc
| |____AnalysisFactory.h
| |____AnalysisInfo.cc
| |____AnalysisInfo.h
| |____AnalysisSteering.cc
| |____AnalysisSteering.h
| |____Event.cc
| |____Event.h
| |____EventReadFromFile.cc
| |____EventReadFromFile.h
| |____EventSim.cc
| |____EventSim.h
| |____EventSource.cc
| |____EventSource.h
| |____main.cc
| |____SourceFactory.cc
| |____SourceFactory.h
|____AnalysisObjects
| |____BraggStatistic.cc
| |____BraggStatistic.h
| |____TotalEnergy.cc
| |____TotalEnergy.h
|____AnalysisPlugins
| |____BGCalc.cc
| |____BGCalc.h
| |____EnergyDist.cc
| |____EnergyDist.h
| |____EventDump.cc
| |____EventDump.h
|____AnalysisUtilities
| |____Constants.cc
| |____Constants.h
|____braggPlot_v06.txt
|____compile
|____util
| |____.DS_Store
| |____class
| | |____cloneClass
| | |____createClass.cc
| | |____info
| |____include
| | |____.DS_Store
| | |____ActiveObserver.h
| | |____ActiveObserver.hpp
| | |____Dispatcher.h
| | |____Dispatcher.hpp
| | |____LazyObserver.h
| | |____LazyObserver.hpp
| | |____Random.h
| | |____Singleton.h
| | |____Singleton.hpp
| |____info
| |____lib
| |____src
| | |____random
| | | |____base
| | | | |____compile
| | | | |____Random.cc
| | | |____info
| | | |____root
| | | | |____compile
| | | | |____RootRandom.cc
| | | | |____RootRandom.h
| | | |____std
| | | | |____compile
| | | | |____StdRandom.cc
| | | | |____StdRandom.h
| | | |____test
| | | | |____compileRandom
| | | | |____testRandom.cc
```

Comment: How do you compile `AnalysisObjects`?

Comment: BTW. OSX uses `.dylib` extension for shared objects, not `.so`.

Comment: @el.pescado i use ` c++-4.8 -std=c++0x -fPIC -shared -o libAnalysisObjects.so *.cc -I../ -I. -Wall`

Comment: @el.pescado so do you think the problem could be the wrong library extension?

Comment: It looks like compiler cannot find symbols `Event::minSize`, `Constants::bgMean` and `Event::energy`, which are defined outside `AnalysisObjects`. Try to link with `AnalysisFramework` and `AnalysisUtilities`.

Comment: I don't think extension is the problem now. However it may be in the future, preventing linker from finding libraries.

Comment: @el.pescado  exactly... But the intention is that the library has to be indipendent, i think... Otherwise it has no sense putting these source codes in differente package. Not?

Comment: @el.pescado i've found the problems are the static members of the class. i'd like to understand better what i've to do with static members when i want create a shared librebry